# Mongoose FindOne returns query and collection instead of document from collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to NodeJS and trying to work on mongoose for my college project,I have been trying to retrieve a document from the collection using the model.findOne() method but, instead of returning a document from the collection, mongoose instead returns a query and model metadata.

adding await before userModel.findOne() simply results in query already executed error from mongoose.

User Schema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

//Define Collection Schema
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    emailId:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    userName:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    password:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    role:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        default: "user"
    },
    
    playlist:[{
        type: String,
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "vidmodel"
    }],

    likes:[{
        type: String,
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "vidmodel"
    }],

    dislikes:[{
        type:  String,
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "vidmodel"
    }]
})

userSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    this.emailId=this.emailId.toLowerCase();
    next();
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('usermodel', userSchema)
```

Function

```
const userModel = require('./models/userModel')

app.post('/user/signup', upload.single(''), async(req,res)=>{
    try{
        const formData = req.body
        const email = formData.email
        const password = formData.password
        existingUser=userModel.findOne({emailId:email}, function(err, user){
            if(user){
                console.log("output of findOne",user)
            }
            if(err){
                console.log(err)
            }
        })
        if(existingUser){
            console.log(existingUser)
        }
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log(err)
    }
})
```

Output:

```
Query {
  _mongooseOptions: {},
  _transforms: [],
  _hooks: Kareem { _pres: Map(0) {}, _posts: Map(0) {} },
  _executionStack: null,
  mongooseCollection: Collection {
    collection: Collection { s: [Object] },
    Promise: [Function: Promise],
    modelName: 'usermodel',
    _closed: false,
    opts: {
      autoIndex: true,
      autoCreate: true,
      schemaUserProvidedOptions: {},
      capped: false,
      Promise: [Function: Promise],
      '$wasForceClosed': undefined
    },
    name: 'usermodels',
    collectionName: 'usermodels',
    conn: NativeConnection {
      base: [Mongoose],
      collections: [Object],
      models: [Object],
      config: {},
      replica: false,
      options: null,
      otherDbs: [],
      relatedDbs: {},
      states: [Object: null prototype],
      _readyState: 1,
      _closeCalled: undefined,
      _hasOpened: true,
      plugins: [],
      id: 0,
      _queue: [],
      _listening: false,
      _connectionString: 'mongodb://localhost/streambytes-dev',
      _connectionOptions: [Object],
      client: [MongoClient],
      '$initialConnection': [Promise],
      db: [Db],
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 27017,
      name: 'streambytes-dev'
    },
    queue: [],
    buffer: false,
    emitter: EventEmitter {
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    }
  },
  model: Model { usermodel },
  schema: Schema {
    obj: {
      emailId: [Object],
      userName: [Object],
      password: [Object],
      role: [Object],
      playlist: [Array],
      likes: [Array],
      dislikes: [Array]
    },
    paths: {
      emailId: [SchemaString],
      userName: [SchemaString],
      password: [SchemaString],
      role: [SchemaString],
      playlist: [SchemaArray],
      likes: [SchemaArray],
      dislikes: [SchemaArray],
      _id: [ObjectId],
      __v: [SchemaNumber]
    },
    aliases: {},
    subpaths: {
      'playlist.$': [ObjectId],
      'likes.$': [ObjectId],
      'dislikes.$': [ObjectId]
    },
    virtuals: { id: [VirtualType] },
    singleNestedPaths: {},
    nested: {},
    inherits: {},
    callQueue: [],
    _indexes: [],
    methods: {},
    methodOptions: {},
    statics: {},
    tree: {
      emailId: [Object],
      userName: [Object],
      password: [Object],
      role: [Object],
      playlist: [Array],
      likes: [Array],
      dislikes: [Array],
      _id: [Object],
      __v: [Function: Number],
      id: [VirtualType]
    },
    query: {},
    childSchemas: [],
    plugins: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    '$id': 3,
    mapPaths: [],
    s: { hooks: [Kareem] },
    _userProvidedOptions: {},
    options: {
      typeKey: 'type',
      id: true,
      _id: true,
      validateBeforeSave: true,
      read: null,
      shardKey: null,
      discriminatorKey: '__t',
      autoIndex: null,
      minimize: true,
      optimisticConcurrency: false,
      versionKey: '__v',
      capped: false,
      bufferCommands: true,
      strictQuery: true,
      strict: true,
      pluralization: true
    },
    '$globalPluginsApplied': true
  },
  op: 'findOne',
  options: {},
  _conditions: { emailId: 'JCD@unatco.com' },
  _fields: undefined,
  _update: undefined,
  _path: undefined,
  _distinct: undefined,
  _collection: NodeCollection {
    collection: Collection {
      collection: [Collection],
      Promise: [Function: Promise],
      modelName: 'usermodel',
      _closed: false,
      opts: [Object],
      name: 'usermodels',
      collectionName: 'usermodels',
      conn: [NativeConnection],
      queue: [],
      buffer: false,
      emitter: [EventEmitter]
    },
    collectionName: 'usermodels'
  },
  _traceFunction: undefined,
  '$useProjection': true
}
```

I tried using callback which does not result in anything, tried the code mentioned in the question which simply results in query and model metadata as the output. using async keyword before findOne simply results in query already executed error. I cannot figure out what is the problem here.

Comment: @ShueiYang I tried the function proposed by you but it simply does not return anything and goes to the else part of the model.findOne () as if document does not exist or is undefined, while the document does exist in the collection specified by the userModel.

Comment: well the issue may come from the request but i can't tell without seeing it, can you show how you make the post request ? or console.log(req.body.email) and see if you see exactly what you expect to see. (the email)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use async/await like this :

```
 app.post('/user/signup', upload.single(''), async(req,res)=>{
     try{
         const formData = req.body
         const email = formData.email
         const password = formData.password
         const user = await userModel.findOne({emailId: email}).exec();
             
             if(user){
                console.log("output of findOne", user)
              // your response logic
             } else {
               console.log("User does not existe") 
             // your response logic
             }
     }catch(err){
         console.log(err)
     });
```

You can choose to use callback or Async/await syntax with try/catch, but not mix together in the single function since the callback will handle his own error, anyway it's better to use async/await if you can it's much more easy to read.

you can check mongoose documentation : https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-findOne

Comment: Please format all code as code.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out query was correctly written but for some reason, VS Code refused to identify the email variable which supplied the value for emailId field. even though the variable did contain proper value, it wasn't being passed to findOne(). simply restarting the system

although why it kept returning query is still unclear to me,